# How to deal with declaration of the primitive type without the initial value known (C++)?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

In some cases it happens for me to declare a variable without knowing its value first like:

```
int a;
if (c1) {
  a = 1;
} else if (c2) {
  a = 2;
} else if (c3) {
  a = -3;
} 
do_something_with(a);
```

Is it the standard professional practice to assign some clearly wrong value like `-1000` anyway (making potential bugs more reproducible) or it is preferred not to add the code that does nothing useful as long as there are no bugs? From one side, looks reasonable to remove randomness, from the other side, magical and even "clearly wrong" numbers somehow do not look attractive.

In many cases it is possible to declare when the value is first known, or use a ternary operator, but here we would need it nested so also rather clumsy.

Declaring inside the block would move the variable out of the scope prematurely.

Or would this case justify the usage of `std::optional<int> a` and `assert(a)` later, making sure we have the value?

EDIT: The bugs I am talking about would occur if suddenly all 3 conditions are false that should "absolutely never happen".

Comment: don't do this `int a = []{if (c1) { return 1; } else if (c2) { return 2; } etc... }();`

Comment: reading your question more carefully, it seems like you are asking for opinions and "best practices". Always initializing variables helps to prevent so many bugs, imho it always justifies to change the code so you can initialize. Sometimes even a clumsy conditional operator is better than an uninitialized value

Comment: If none of c1, c2, c3 is true you end up with an uninitialised value – and that might be equal to one of those values c1, c2 or c3 imply, which might be critical. If you can live with a default, then I'd initialise with that one (or use that one in a final else) – if none of c1, c2 or c3 being true and still going on might result in critical errors, then you could consider preventing this by throwing an exception. At least spotting the issue in debug mode by an assertion could be an alternative.

Comment: Some 'obviously wrong value' is called a 'sentinel' value. The important thing about is: *If* you introduce one, you must assure that it is not in the range of legal values of your application *and* `do_something_with` must be able to handle the sentinel as well (or you call it only if the value differs from the sentinel). If the entire range of `int` is valid, then there's no meaningful sentinel and you should fall back to another solution.

Comment: Yet another important note: Reading an uninitialised value is *undefined behaviour*. You invalidate your entire programme if none of c1, c2 or c3 is set and you still just continue.

Comment: If `c1`, `c2`, and `c3` are all false (or zero) then `do_something_with(a)` will have undefined behaviour, so the function should not be called, so I would initialise `a` to a value that is not set by any of the `if`/`else` blocks (say, `0` in your case) and change the call to `if (a != 0) do_something_with(a);`.  If you can *guarantee* that one of the conditions `c1`, `c2`, or `c3` will be true (non-zero) then options include using your code "as is" or eliminating the variable entirely e.g. to `do_something_with(c1 ? 1 : (c2 ? 2 : (c3 ? -3 : dummy)));` where `dummy` can be any value.

Comment: @Peter If this guarantee exists we actually don't need the dummy any more, could be `c1 ? 1 : c2 ? 2 : -3`, because if c1 and c2 are not set, c3 must be. But if it ever still occurs that there isn't any of the three set we'd still behave as if c3 was. Acceptable? Only Audrius knows...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would introduce a default value. I'm usually using MAX value of the type for this.

Shortest you can do this with the ternary operator like this:

```
#include <climits>

int a = c1 ? 1 : c2 ? 2 : c3 ? -3 : INT_MAX;

do_something_with(a);
```

Comment: While lambda - based solution also looks very interesting, this somewhat appears to me an overkill. Putting values from climits will ensure that the tests would fail predictably, and such value is less likely to pass as good than 0. Finally, there are no magic numbers like -1000.

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know the most popular and safest way is using inline lambda call. Note that the `if` should be exhaustive (I added `SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE` as a placeholder). I suppose that if you don't know what to put in final `else` block you should consider a few options:

- using `optional` and putting `none` in the `else`,
- throwing exception that describes the problem,
- putting `assert` if logically this situation should never happen

```
const int a = [&] {
  if (c1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (c2) {
    return 2;
  } else if (c3) {
    return -3;
  } else {
    return SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE;
  }
}();
do_something_with(a);
```

In a situation when the initialization logic duplicates somewhere you can simply extract the lambda to a named function as other answers suggest

Comment: I don't consider that superior to just initialising a with SOME_DEFAULT_VALUE in original code or add an else with the default assignment. It's even poorer than the other (in the meanwhile deleted answer) with a separate, independent function as it cannot even be reused if the same code is needed at multiple locations (well, it could at least inside the same function if you assign the lambda to a variable; admitted, you mention the option of independent function at least).

Comment: Landing in an unhandled case could also be the place to `assert` or `throw`.

Comment: In many cases I do not have neither easy default value that would make any sense nor something that could pass as null without wrappers.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas Then very last variant of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69205800/1312382) comes into play – especially as, if neither default nor null is feasable, you have some complex data type involved that might not even be default-constructible...

Comment: If you fix the return type to `int`, you don't need an extra return statement. Then it can be an assertion, `__builtin_unreachable`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the safest option, if you dont want this other value (its just useless), then it may lead to really subtle bug which may be hard to find. Therefore I would throw an expectation when any of the conditions is not met:

```
int get_init_value(bool c1, bool c2, bool c3) {
    if (c1) { return 1; }
    else if (c2) { return 2; }
    else if (c3) { return -3; }
    throw std::logic_error("noone of conditions to define value was met");
}
```

That way we avoid getting some weird values that want actually match our code, but they would compile anyways ( debugging it may take a lot of time). I consider it way better than just assigning it some clearly wrong value.

Comment: Ah, finally one seeing the option of an exception! +1

Comment: It should never be so that all three are false, but if already happened, clearly a bug and throwing would help to find it sooner.

Comment: @Aconcagua your way of thinking is why "everyone" avoids exceptions, which is blatantly wrong and reinforces fallacious assumptions. C++ exceptions are free, when they are not thrown. Now think about it, how often do you run buggy code in production and if your code is fundamentally broken, why are you concerned about performance above all things? Logic errors are only relevant during programming stage, covered by tests, if such exception is thrown in production, depending on what your code is responsible for, you could be fired. Performance in that case is the least of your worries.

Comment: @Aconcagua using exceptions for general error handling is of course slow. But its a logical error we're talking about. Something that should be checked for if impossible to enforce using compile-time machinery, but not something that should ever realistically happen in, well, real life. In this case this is equivalent to assert in C, that strongly *asserts* that programmer is doing something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237181/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-kaihaku).

Answer (score 4):

**Opinion based answer!**

I know the example is a simplification of a real, more complex example, but IMHO it seems nowadays this kind of design issue emerge more often, and people sometimes kinda tend to over-complicate it.

Isn't it the whole purpose of a variable to hold some value? Thus isn't having a default value for this variable also a feasible thing?

So what exactly is wrong with:

```
int a = -1000; // or some other value meant to used for undefined
if (c1) {
  a = 1;
} else if (c2) {
  a = 2;
} else if (c3) {
  a = -3;
} 
do_something_with(a);
```

It is simple and readable... No lambdas, exceptions and other stuff making the code unnecessary complicated...

Or like:

```
int a;
if (c1) {
  a = 1;
} else if (c2) {
  a = 2;
} else if (c3) {
  a = -3;
} else {
  a = -1000;  // default for unkown state
}
do_something_with(a);
```

You could introduce a constant `const int undefined = -1000;` and use the constant.
Or an enum if c1, c2, c3 are states in some sort (which it most likely is)...
You could rearrange the code to eliminate the variable if it is not needed elsewhere.

```
if (c1) {
  do_something_with(1);
} else if (c2) {
  do_something_with(2);
} else if (c3) {
  do_something_with(-3);
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the simplicity, especially of very last variant... +1.

Comment: What's wrong is that its a meaningless number that nobody knows what it means. It may be acceptable in a sloppy C library, but decent C libraries use defined constants for that which have a purposeful name, for example `lauxlib.h:154:#define LUA_NOREF       (-2)` and `lauxlib.h:155:#define LUA_REFNIL      (-1)` in `luajit`. In C++ this in my opinion is unacceptable when we have a way to define typed constants (read: not just an integer, but a whole new type), or just class enums such as `result.invalid`, `result.one`, `result.two`...

Answer (score 3):

I understand your real code is much more complicated than the outline presented, but IMHO the main problem here is

> should we `do_something_with(a)` at all if `a` is undefined,

rather than

> what the initial value should be.

And the solution might be adding explicitly some status flag like `a_is_defined` to the actual parameter `a` instead of using magic constans.

```
int a = 0;
bool a_is_defined = false;
```

When you set them both according to `c...` conditions and pass them to `do_something()` you'll be able to make a clear distinction between a specific `if(a_is_defined) {...}` path and a default (error handling?) `else {...}`.

Or even provide separate routines to explicitly handle both paths one level earlier: `if(a_is_defined) do_someting_with(a); else do_something_else();`.

Comment: I don't like the additional bool (`do_something_else()` might be called from an additional `else` clause as in which we simply return), apart from good focus on actual problem...

Comment: It is probably then better with std::optional ?

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas Probably. :)